# Remove punctuation and HTML entity with hadoop Wordcount in java

Tags: java, hadoop, html-entities

I try to remove all the punctuation (" .,;:!?()[] " ) as well as all the HTML entities (&...) using the Wordcount code in java from hadoop Apache (https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html). If I remove only the punctuation with the delimiters it works very well as if I remove the HTML entities with unescapeHtml(word) from the StringEscapeUtils package.

But when I run both of them together the HTML entities are still present and I don't see what is wrong with my code.

```
    public static class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString(),".,;:!?()[]\t\n\r",true);
        while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String next_word = itr.nextToken();
            if(next_word.contains("&")){

                next_word = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(next_word);
            }
                            word.set(next_word);
                            context.write(word, one);
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone explain me what's the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic case example for the use of [regular expressions](https://blog.usejournal.com/regular-expressions-a-complete-beginners-tutorial-c7327b9fd8eb) in order to filter out the HTML entities and symbols of punctuation from the text inside the input files.

In order to do that, we need to create the two regular expressions that are going to be used to match the HTML entities and punctuation respectively and remove them from the text to finally set as key-value pairs the remaining valid words.

Starting with the HTML entities like `&nbsp;`, `&lt;`, and `&gt;`, we can figure out that those tokens always start with the `&` character and end with the `;` character with a number of alphabetical characters in-between. So based on the RegEx syntax (which you can study on your own, it's really valuable if you haven't yet), the following expression matches all these tokens:

```
&.*?\w+;
```

(As we can test as well with the online regex tester [here](https://regex101.com/)):
[image]

Up next for the punctuation symbols we can simply match those by simply looking for characters that are neither letters nor numbers (and also not whitespace, of course), such as the next regular expression does:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]
```

(Again testing with the online regex tester [here](https://regex101.com/) after removing the HTML entities that got matched with the previous regular expression):

[image]

So in order to use those regular expressions we simply can use the `replaceAll()` method that based on the regex of the first parameter change all the tokens matching with it to what the second parameter string is. Over here we can change all the matched tokens to a simple whitespace and proceed to remove all double spaces in the end so only the valid words remain to be put as key in the key-value pairs of the mappers.

So the program now looks like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class WordCount 
{
  public static class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>
  {

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
    {
      String line = value.toString();

       // clean up the text of the line by removing...
      line = line.replaceAll("&.*?\\w+;", " ")               // HTML entities...
                  .replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]", " ")         // punctuation...
                  .replaceAll("\\s+", " ");               // and getting rid of double spaces


      // if the line has remaining words after the cleanup...
      if(line != null && !line.trim().isEmpty())
      {
          String[] words = line.split(" ");   // split the text to words

          // set each word as key to the key-value pair
          for(String word : words)
              context.write(new Text(word), one);
      }  
    }
  }

  public static class IntSumReducer extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> 
  {
    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
    {
      int sum = 0;
      for (IntWritable val : values) 
      {
        sum += val.get();
      }

      result.set(sum);
      context.write(key, result);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
  {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
  }
}
```

And by using the following text file contents as input:

```
hello &nbsp; people! how are you?
i am better than ever how about &lt; you &gt;?
i just found three &euro; on the floor....
so damn lucky good for you..!
thank you @@@@@ :)
```

This is the given output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this incredible answer! This help me a lot

Comment: Tick/check this answer as the accepted answer if it helped you with your issue.